# Updating board in oracle form

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle9i, oracleforms

Is there anything like thread in Oracle forms for updating one part? I want to create a message box and update that part with the new events, so I need to have something like thread or Timer in my oracle form. Any examples or ideas?

I am working with Oracle forms 6i, but I can convert to 10g also. My oracle server version is 9.

Comment: There's a massive difference between Forms 6.0 and 6i (the former was client server, the latter could eb deployed as client/server or webapp). can you clarify

Comment: Probably one way of doing it is to have the part that needs updating in a separate block, and when the timer event occurs, refresh that block

Comment: How I can create timer,do u have any example?

Answer (score 1):

The help file/ online documentation in Oracle Forms features sample code on creating timers.

Create a timer, perhaps under `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger

```
DECLARE
    timer_id timer;
begin
    timer_id := CREATE_TIMER('TIMER1',20000,REPEAT);
end;
```

This will create a repeating timer which will fire every 20 seconds.

Now under `WHEN-TIMER-EXPIRED` trigger write the timer expiration handler

```
declare 
     timer_id timer;

begin
     -- code for updating the relevant field(s) 
end;
```

Comment: Hi I face with problem would you read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517499/problem-with-timer-in-oracle-form