# problem with timer in oracle form

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am working on an application that created by oracle forms(6i).
I try to use timer in one of my forms every thing was fine during testing and I move my form to production.
when I move to production when I open my form, I try to access to another form when my form was opened I faced with problem. 
unfortunately, I don't know why my menu not working correctly, I mean my menu open another form when this form is running.

there isn't any relation between menu and that form, kindly please advise me about it. also in those systems with old specification rendering of application face with problem. I mean I have a main form with menu that contain a background picture, system flashing for rendering that background.

I create my table according to this post and it is working fine

[Updating board in oracle form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846821/updating-board-in-oracle-form)

I changed timer length from 300 until 1000 no effect :(

I am working with Oracle forms 6i, but I can convert to 10g also. My oracle server version is 9.

> my timer:

Triger WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE

```
DECLARE
    timer_id timer;

BEGIN   
    timer_id := CREATE_TIMER('TIMER1',1000,REPEAT);
END;
```

Trigger WHEN-TIMER-EXPIRED

```
declare 
    timer_id timer;
    nv_temp varchar2(400);
    nv_temp_ch varchar2(2);
begin
    IF length(:NB_VTB.NB_STATUS) > 4 THEN
        nv_temp := substr(:NB_VTB.NB_STATUS,2,length(:NB_VTB.NB_STATUS));

        IF(:parameter.TP_STR_LEN = 0 )THEN
                nv_temp := nv_temp ||'    ('||to_char(SYSDATE,'hh:mm:ss')||')   ';          
        END IF;
        nv_temp_ch := substr(:NB_VTB.NB_STATUS,1,1);

        if (nv_temp_ch = ' ') then
            nv_temp_ch := '`';
        else
            nv_temp := replace(nv_temp,'`',' ');    
        end if;

         nv_temp := nv_temp || nv_temp_ch;  

        :NB_VTB.NB_STATUS := nv_temp;
        :parameter.TP_STR_LEN := :parameter.TP_STR_LEN + 1;

        IF :parameter.TP_STR_LEN > length(:NB_VTB.NB_STATUS)THEN
            :parameter.TP_STR_LEN := 0;
            :NB_VTB.NB_STATUS := FPG_FORM_STARTUP.ffn_get_status;
        END IF;
    END IF;
end;
```

Comment: We need to stop timer, but I dont know where or how I can find my form with not using and how I can stop my timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, it should work.

```
    PROCEDURE Delete_Timer IS
         tm_id  TIMER;
    BEGIN
      tm_id:=Find_Timer('TIMER1');
      IF NOT Id_Null(tm_id) THEN
        Delete_Timer(tm_id);
      ELSE
        Message('Timer '||' has already been cancelled.');
      END IF;
    END;
```